# ASP.NET Core MongoDB - storing Bitmap List in collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb

```
public class ExampleModel
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonElement("id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("title")]
        [MaxLength(64)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("images")]
        [MaxLength(4)]
        public List<Bitmap> Images { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a bunch of problems here.

Firstly, will `List<Bitmap>` work with MongoDB out of the box? You will probably say "just check it yourself", but first I need some code behind, and I don't want to write it two times if it needs some additional things to work.

Secondly, for which I have no idea, can I limit size of single Bitmap? It will be used for HttpPost, user can add up to 4 (subject to change) images, and to ensure MongoDB size limit (16MB) is not exceeded, I should somehow keep it limited. `MaxLength` should work for count limit, no idea how to ensure size limit.

Comment: mongodb doesn't know what a bitmap is and will likely crap out. you can store binary files in the db as byte arrays if it won't exceed 16mb. or you gotta use gridFS. check out [this](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/File-Storage.html) for a simpler alternative to gridFS.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ I don't have plans to exceed the limit. And your solution assumes moving Image outside of the collection to own collection, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: then simply store the image data as a `List<byte[]>` on the entity

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ oh dear, that makes things WAY easier. I was not aware you can convert Bitmap to byte array. Now there is a problem with size limitation, but I bet i can make it from .cshtml perspective.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert the Bitmap to a byte[]

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then in your DB model

```
public List<byte[]> Images {get; set;}
```

Also keep in mind your document must not exceed 16 MB